# How to disable things I post to an open public Google+ community (not mine) from showing up in my main public feed?

Tags: google-plus

Whenever I post a message to a community it pops up in my feed like a usual post visible to all the followers. But I'd like it to be visible only inside the community. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can I control whether my public community posts appear on my profile page?

While in communities:

- Click the  icon
- Select Settings
- Scroll to Show your Google+ communities posts on the Posts tab of your Google+ profile
- Choose either on or off

Comment: "Click the icon" - what icon?